# Atom execution error - /usr/bin/env: 'node’: No such file or directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash, npm, filesystems

I am new to coding using Atom, and I keep running into the same error message when trying to execute Javascript code.

`bash: line 1: node: command not found /usr/bin/env: ‘node’: No such file or directory`

I have looked around, but all of the solutions that other's suggested do not work for me.Any help is very much appreciated!

EDIT - the full error message looks like this:

`[Command: bash -c ''/home/jacob/.var/app/io.atom.Atom/data/packages/script/node_modules/.bin/babel' --filename '/home/jacob/code/new.js' --config-file /home/jacob/.var/app/io.atom.Atom/data/packages/script/lib/grammars/babel.config.js < '/home/jacob/code/new.js'| node'] bash: line 1: node: command not found /usr/bin/env: ‘node’: No such file or directory`

Comment: The error message says `bla bla bla ...   /home/jacob/code/new.js' | node']  ...`.  So the first command (the bash here) output is being piped into the `node` command.  `node` must be installed on your system.  And you must be able to call it with your user.  My guess here, is that you do not have NodeJS installed, or the path to `node` is not defined in  your `PATH` environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue on my Mac while I was running JavaScript code on Atom. The issue was resolved after I installed NodeJS.